How to create a custom next() function?
In C++, I need a custom iterator that goes over an array, not all elements of which are marked as valid. Thus, the next() function must be a bit smarter than the one just doing ++iterator; I need it to check if the next element is valid, skip it if it's not, and so forth till a valid element is found or the array end occurs. Just wondering if there's a more elegant way to do so, rather than checking all elements in a loop one by one. For example:
struct MyDataType {
    // ...
    bool _flagValid;
    // ...

    bool is_valid() { return _flagValid; }
};

MyDataType DataArray[DATA_ARRAY_SIZE];
// ...
uint32_t count_valid_ones () {
    auto count = 0U;
    for (auto &d: DataArray) {
        if (d.is_valid) count++;
    }
    return count;
}

But this way would be preferable:
uint32_t count_valid_ones () {
    auto count = 0U;
    auto __range = ValidOnesOnly(DataArray)
    for (auto &d: __range) count++;
    return count;
}


If you can use C++20 and std::ranges you can just get a filter_view

I would create a struct which contains a reference to an array of objects as a wrapper. That struct can then implement an iterator which only yields items which meet a condition.

If the intention is just to count, you can even use auto n = std::ranges::count_if(DataArray, &MyDataType::is_valid); - see count_if docs

Minor note: bool is_valid() { return _flagValid; } should probably be bool is_valid() const { return _flagValid; }

__range is a name reserved for the implementation. You could also simplify the counting with return std::distance(begin(range), end(range))
